# How to execute function after 10s idle time in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Example:

Actually how to execute a function each 10s if system idle.

Example:

```
setInterval(function () {
         test();
         },10000); 
//for every 10 Sec
```

I am looking for 10s if system idle. Please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: how would you identify `system idle` is the first question here..

Comment: is it possible to find system idle ,, like no movement in mouse & keyboard in jquery

Comment: check https://github.com/kidh0/jquery.idle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check for `mousemove`, `keyup` and `keypress` event on `document` and call your `settimeout` and `cleartimeout` inside that as below:

```
var interval;
$(document).on('mousemove keyup keypress',function(){
    clearTimeout(interval);//clear it as soon as any event occurs
  //do any process and then call the function again
    settimeout();//call it again
})

function settimeout(){
    interval=setTimeout(function(){
    alert("Idle for 10s"); 
  },10000)
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/06k2xzwv/)**

Answer (score 1):

setInterval is the function to use, but if you to run only when system is idle, you need to reset the interval whenever something else happens.

so you do:

```
timeout = setTimeout(function() { test();},10000);
```

and when something else happens, you do

```
clearTimeout(timeout); //clear the timeout
//do stuff;
timeout = setTimeout(function() { test();},10000); //and re-activate it when done
```

or more generally:

```
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(function(){ test(); }, 3000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
setTimeout(function() { test (); }, 10000);
```

Comment: Code only answers are very likely to be unhelpful for future visitors and even the OP himself. Consider editing your answer to contain explaination with the code.

Answer (score -1):

Try This-
Call function at any of event which you think usefull

```
function test(){      
   // Use your code here...
}
setTimeout(test, 10000);
```

Comment: Code only answers are very likely to be unhelpful for future visitors and even the OP himself. Consider editing your answer to contain explaination with the code.